# How to save list of user Ids in a local list in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I have a collection in Firestore, I am attaching the structure below -

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

The **'following'** collection is the primary collection which consists of collections of user ids, every user id has **'usersFollowing'** collection which consists of all the user ids whom the current user is following.

What I want is to save all the user ids of 'userFollowing' collection into a list locally when a user log in, how can I do it?

I tried but unable to retrieve data, I am attaching my code below,

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('following')
        .doc(widget.currentUser.id)
        .collection('userFollowing').get();

List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> docs = snapshot.docs;
List<FollowersId> ids = docs.map((doc) => FollowersId.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
```

### FollowersId Model

```
class FollowersId {
  
  String userFollowerId;
  FollowersId({userFollowerId});

  factory FollowersId.fromDocument(doc) {
    return FollowersId(
      userFollowerId: doc.data(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can save it to local database, [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) or similar.

Comment: I already have the database model in firestore, the only thing is to retrieve the information here in this case the userFollowing id's.

Answer (score 2):

To get data you can do this:-

```
List<String> ids=[];
  QuerySnapshot snapshot=await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('following')
    .document(widget.currentUser.id).collection("userFollowing").getDocuments();
  snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) { 
    ids.add(doc.documentID);
  });
```

after execution of above code all the ids will be stored in the list ids.
And if you want to store it locally to your device then you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).

Comment: What does doc.documentID mean ? I mean what is documentID, there is not such variable in the table.

Comment: doc.Document id means that you will get the document id of that document. like in your case it is 113000 and so on

Comment: There is no such function doc.documentID, I don't know whether it got deprecated or not. If possible can you give me any documentation where it is written.

Comment: Well in [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) you can see it is there but if it is depricated you may store the document id as field in the document while its creation.